# Why does my installation of Tomcat not work?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

I have a problem regarding the installation of Apache-Tomcat. I've downloaded the Zip-File [Picture Download Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOTx0.png) , unpacked it and saved it, set the environmental variables JAVA-HOME (set the value to jdk) , JRE_HOME (set the value to jre) and CATALINA_Home (set to apache tomcat) but it doesn't seem to work. After starting startup.bat with cmd.exe, following occurs: [Picture Startup.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3adz.png) Typing localhost:8080 into the browser, following occurs: [Localhost Error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LchFH.png) and [Localhost 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWjLP.png)

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of code, log files, error messages into you Questions.  Copy and paste the text into your question and then format it.   See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/139985

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the sister site [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) as it does not involve any programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error messages in your screenshot, I would think that tomcat wants to create subdirectories but does not have the required rights.
c:\Porgram Files\ can only be written with administrative rights, so you could test it (but only test it) to start it with administrative rights (e.g. open the cmd windows with administrative rights).

If that solves the issue: Do not run tomcat as administrator. Instead grant full access to the folders required (I think it is mainly temp, work and logs folder that tomcat has to write to.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately starting it with administrative righs doesn't solve the issue. I get exactly the same error messages...

Comment: I tried it again and this time it worked. Thank you!